# Uploading images with foreign key constraint

Tags: codeigniter, foreign-keys, default-value

I have a foreign key constraint in an `images` table which is the `user_id` column in my `users` table. When I try to upload a new image, I get the DB error

> 1364: Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value.

I suspect it’s because the code is looking for a value to add to the `images` column. I originally thought that if the session is set, loading an image would automatically identify the user who’s uploading the image.

Question: How can I include data that would merge the two tables when a user uploads an image? Here is the code in the controller that uploads the image:

```
function upload() {
        //$filename = md5(uniqid(rand(), false));
        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => 'uploads',
            'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
            //'file_name' => $filename,
            'max_size' => 200,
            'max_width' => 1024,
            'max_height' => 768     
        );          


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(empty($this->session->userdata['email'])){
               redirect(site_url().'/main/login/');

        }else       
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload())
        {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();

        $data['name'] = $file_data['file_name'];
        $data['file'] = $file_data['file_path'];
        $data['file_type'] = $file_data['file_type'];
        $data['file_size'] = $file_data['file_size'];           
        $data['date_uploaded'] = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

The images_model:

```
function save_image($data){     
    $this->db->insert('images', $data);
}
```

[The 'images' table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q906.png)

Appreciate ALL input and suggestions.

Comment: Where you are calling the model function?

Comment: @DanishAli. Someone suggested I added the $data ($data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');)and it's working now. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your application only users can upload image ...
Then before uploading image you should check if user is signed or not and get user id ...

when you want to add new record to images table you must add user_id to $data array

$data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); // or anything you added to session

.....

Comment: That's what I was missing. I'm a newbie, but I'm learning:) Working now. Thanks for the feedback.